# Нужно ли тире в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Тебе (–) конец.

Нужно ли тире в данном случае? Если да, то обязательно ли оно?

Comment: Не совсем понял второй вопрос. Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вас интересует, насколько грубой ошибкой будет отсутствие тире, при условии, что оно необходимо?

Comment: Факультативно ли оно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В толковом словаре:
[**конец**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%5B%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%5D&help=1)
**<Конец** *(кому-чему). **неизм.; в функции сказуемого.*** Всё кончено для кого-либо, чего-либо.
*Конец карьере. Конец праздной жизни, хватит. **Если не выручишь, мне конец!***

В абсолютном большинстве случаев тире не ставится.
*Тебе конец!* — фильм.
*Тебе конец, хапуга!* — книга Кирилла Казанцева.
*Тебе конец, убийца* — книга Ричарда С. Пратера.
*Никотиновый леденец, тебе конец* — статья в МК.

*Останешься тут по такой зиме, и **тебе конец**, Бирк, сын Борки* (А. Линдгрен. Рони, дочь разбойника); *Тебе не спрятаться, Лили, — продолжал Райли. — Если останешься в городе, **тебе конец*** (С. Брюер. Пули).

Так что тире в конструкции "тебе конец" не нужно.
Вполне возможно, что в каком-то случае оно и будет оправдано авторской задумкой, но без контекста об этом рассуждать нет пользы.